# FileSystemWatcher: Ignore temporary and ghost files created

Tags: java, file, filesystemwatcher, temporary

I have implemented a watcher service in java which monitors folders for changes. Whenever a word file gets created,modified or deleted, it creates a lot of temporary files and ghost files. My question is how to ignore these files? I tried to see if they are hidden files, but they are not. I want a solution which works with all kind of applications not just microsoft word.

Thanks

Comment: word's temp file has a `~` at the end (IIRC) and I believe the entire M$ office package does so however each program has it's own convention with temp files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My quick test shows the opposite: both the DOS shell and the Java IO API says that Word tmp files are hidden, ie.:

```
DIR /A:H
```

lists Word tmp files.

The following simple test program reports Word tmp files as hidden ones:

```java
import java.io.File;

public class Hidden{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      File dir = new File(args[0]);
      for (File file : dir.listFiles()){
         System.out.println(file + " is hidden? " + file.isHidden());
      }     
   }
}
```

Test env: WinXP Professional + JDK 1.6

Comment: this is not entirely true.
when the "FileSystemWatcher" indicates a creation of file "~wrdxxxx.tmp"
the "DIR /A:H" shows something else "~$b ...docx"

and the "~wrdxxxx.tmp" seams as a file which is not hidden.